# Unexpected in macro formal parameter list Error

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I'm an intern student and my boss told me to do porting from Linux c to Visual C++.

When I built the coding, I found this error "unexpected in macro formal parameter list", here is the code

```
#define cache_info(format, msg...)  
    do { \
        ;\
    } while (0)
```

I don't know what is wrong and what the coding is for .

I can't also ask the Linux programmer since he is out. Can someone help me ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like your version of Visual C++ doesn't support variadic macros.

you might need to try something like this to get it to work.

```
#define FUNC(foo)  ThisFunc foo

void ThisFunc(int, ...);

int main()
{
    FUNC((123, 456));
}
```

or you could just be missing a comma?....

```
#define cache_info(format, msg,...)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem could be from one of two things.

First, your macro is defined as

```
cache_info(format, msg...)
```

But you probably meant to write

```
cache_info(format, msg, ...)
```

Though this could just be a typo in your original post.

More importantly, though, macros with variable numbers of arguments ("variadic macros") are not supported in C++; they exist only in C.  If you're trying to compile this C code with a C++ compiler, the compiler should give you an error here because the code isn't legal C++.

Answer (score -1):

if using Windows 64 bit OS, & visual studio, try after running this bat file : \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat

It will register env settings. It worked for me..

Comment: The reason you do not want to do this is because this will not be building a 64-bit library.

Also, this will not fix the issue because the macro can't use this type of variadic parameter in C++ (as someone mentioned this only works in C as discussed earlier).

I propose never to intermix 32-bit and 64-bit code in a solution.  Rebuild it all in 64-bit and it will be faster and cleaner when it comes to memory allocation and no longer needing a Windows-on-Windows session to carry the 32-bit emulated code on a 64-bit OS.